# Security Validation Error when trying to create list item across site collections using Javascipt SP2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, javascript

I'm trying to create a list item across another site collection using JavaScript. When trying to call the following function I receive this error.

"request failed. the security validation for this page is invalid. click back in your browser"

```
function CPECalendar(ApprovalInfo) {
var siteUrl = '/sites/npeeng';
var context = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Activations");
var item = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
var oListItem = oList.addItem(item);
oListItem.set_item("Location", "TESTING, PLEASE DISREGARD");
oListItem.update();
context.load(oListItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(silentSuccess, failure);
```

}

I've read in numerous places about AllowingUnsafeUpdates, but not sure if that pertains to this exact problem or works with js. Is there a viable solution I can use with JavaScript? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot make cross-sitecollection calls from JSOM in SharePoint 2010.

Here is a similar issue for your reference:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1853212-62ac-4a15-a47f-e27bc1c35187/hot-to-get-list-which-is-located-in-different-site-collection-using-ecmascript?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

> The scope of client object model is site collection, you cannot access
> to the content out of the current site collection.
>
> Additionally, making a call from one SharePoint site to another is not
> allowed because both of these scenarios would result in cross-site
> scripting.